# c# office word interop get table style

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I want to find a certain style in an exsiting word document and replace a certain table style with another table style. When I tried to get the style from a table, it's not something meaningful.

For example, when I output the style to console it returns "System.__ComObject". I want something like "Table Classic 2" so that I can do a comparison and then set to an appropriate style.

Here is my testing code:

```
Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
                oWord.Visible = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Word.Application is started");

                object fileName = @"G:\test.docx";

                Word.Document oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(ref fileName, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);

                Word.Table oTable = oDoc.Tables[1];
                //oTable.set_Style("Table Classic 2");
                Console.WriteLine( "table style" + oTable.get_Style());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one answer my question. I tried to do this in VBA and here is what I have:

```
For Each objtable In ActiveDocument.Tables

        If objtable.Style = "Table Grid" Then
            objtable.Style = "Grid Table 4"
        End If

Next
```